# Real world examples of websites using oauth2 for authorization

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, authorization, single-sign-on

I have read that oauth2 can be used for both authorization as well as authentication. I have often encountered the 2nd usecase where when I want to login to a new website where I don't already have account, I can login using my google/fb/github/etc account. But, I still don't quite know some real world examples of the former 1st use case of authorization. I would like to know some websites which are using oauth2 for authorization (NOT authentication) and would like to see the real use case in play.

Comment: Please do not cross-post on StackExchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed usage of OAuth 2.0's authorization features happens on virtually every app on a mobile phone, it is less frequently used in webapps. However, there are web applications out there that interact e.g. with your Github data, Google drive/mail/contacts, Facebook timeline etc. An example of the former is Travis:
https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/github-oauth-scopes/
and some examples of the latter are listed here:
https://venturebeat.com/2012/04/24/google-drive-third-party-apps/
(though judging from the date, that list must be outdated by now...)